# ACL error when trying to send mail via Oracle UTL_SMTP

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-24247

I was trying to send an email via oracle utl_smtp, but every time i execute the apex_mail_p.mail procedure i get an ACL error, to be more precise it's the error ORA-24247. But i've created the acl, added the right previliege and also added the host and port to the ACL. I don't understand why it's giving me an error.

This is the code:

```
    -- create acl
begin
        dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
                acl             => 'gmail.xml',
                description     => 'Normal Access',
                principal       => 'CONNECT',
                is_grant        => TRUE,
                privilege       => 'connect',
                start_date      => null,
                end_date        => null
        );
end;
/

-- add priviliege to acl
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege ( 
  acl       => 'gmail.xml',
  principal    => 'MY_PROJECT',
  is_grant    => TRUE, 
  privilege    => 'connect', 
  start_date    => null, 
  end_date    => null); 
end;
/
-- assign host, port to acl
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
  acl => 'gmail.xml',
  host => 'localhost',
  lower_port => 25,
  upper_port => 25);
end;
/



create or replace package apex_mail_p
is
   g_smtp_host      varchar2 (256)     := 'localhost';
   g_smtp_port      pls_integer        := 25;
   g_smtp_domain    varchar2 (256)     := 'gmail.com';
   g_mailer_id constant varchar2 (256) := 'Mailer by Oracle UTL_SMTP';
   -- send mail using UTL_SMTP
   procedure mail (
      p_sender in varchar2
    , p_recipient in varchar2
    , p_subject in varchar2
    , p_message in varchar2
   );
end;
/
create or replace package body apex_mail_p
is
   -- Write a MIME header
   procedure write_mime_header (
      p_conn in out nocopy utl_smtp.connection
    , p_name in varchar2
    , p_value in varchar2
   )
   is
   begin
      utl_smtp.write_data ( p_conn
                          , p_name || ': ' || p_value || utl_tcp.crlf
      );
   end;
   procedure mail (
      p_sender in varchar2
    , p_recipient in varchar2
    , p_subject in varchar2
    , p_message in varchar2
   )
   is
      l_conn           utl_smtp.connection;
      nls_charset    varchar2(255);
   begin
      -- get characterset
      select value
      into   nls_charset
      from   nls_database_parameters
      where  parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
      -- establish connection and autheticate
      l_conn   := utl_smtp.open_connection (g_smtp_host, g_smtp_port);
      utl_smtp.ehlo(l_conn, g_smtp_domain);  
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn, 'auth login');
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn,utl_encode.text_encode('mymail@gmail.com', nls_charset, 1));
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn, utl_encode.text_encode('mypassword123', nls_charset, 1));
      -- set from/recipient
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn, 'MAIL FROM: <'||p_sender||'>');
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn, 'RCPT TO: <'||p_recipient||'>');
      -- write mime headers
      utl_smtp.open_data (l_conn);
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'From', p_sender);
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'To', p_recipient);
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'Subject', p_subject);
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'Content-Type', 'text/plain');
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'X-Mailer', g_mailer_id);
      utl_smtp.write_data (l_conn, utl_tcp.crlf);
      -- write message body
      utl_smtp.write_data (l_conn, p_message);
      utl_smtp.close_data (l_conn);
      -- end connection
      utl_smtp.quit (l_conn);
   exception
      when others
      then
         begin
           utl_smtp.quit(l_conn);
         exception
           when others then
             null;
         end;
         raise_application_error(-20000,'Failed to send mail due to the following error: ' || sqlerrm);   
   end;
end;
/



begin
   apex_mail_p.mail('mymail@gmail.com', 'test@gmail.com', 'Test', 'Its only a test');
end;
/
```

Comment: look at the views - dba_network_acl_privileges and dba_network_acls and see if they are correct.  To make sure it is not a network issue, login to the db server through a command line, and execute telnet on port 25 and see what you get.

Comment: I did select * from dba_network_acls and all the privileges are set to "Connect", also i executed telnet localhost 25 and it gave me this : 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP o15sm3627998wrp.12 - gsmtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Replace `principal` arguments with your database user names,
- Add resolve privilege also,
- Using redundant `begin..end` block is unnecessary.

*So you may consider using the one below :*

```
    -- create acl
    begin
      dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
      acl             => 'gmail.xml',
      description     => 'Normal Access',
      principal       => 'DB_USER',
      is_grant        => TRUE,
      privilege       => 'connect',
      start_date      => null,
      end_date        => null);

    -- add priviliege to acl
      dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege ( 
      acl       => 'gmail.xml',
      principal    => 'DB_USER',
      is_grant    => TRUE, 
      privilege    => 'connect', 
      start_date    => null, 
      end_date    => null); 

      dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege ( 
      acl       => 'gmail.xml',
      principal    => 'DB_USER',
      is_grant    => TRUE, 
      privilege    => 'resolve', 
      start_date    => null, 
      end_date    => null);       

      -- assign host, port to acl
      dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
      acl => 'gmail.xml',
      host => 'localhost',
      lower_port => 25,
      upper_port => 25);
    end;
    /
```

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros Özhan for your answer, turns out i was using the wrong database user.

Answer (score 1):

`host` is the hostname you like to connect, i.e. the gmail server. I assume gmail does not permit plain smtp, you must use port 465 for SSL or 587 for TLS/STARTTLS.

```
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
  acl => 'gmail.xml',
  host => 'smtp.gmail.com', -- or host => 'gmail.com', - I never used gmail in Oracle
  lower_port => 465,
  upper_port => 465);
end;
```

You could also try

```
begin
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
  acl => 'gmail.xml',
  host => '*');
end;
```

However, then the Oracle DB can connect to any server on any port, so for security reasons you should use it only for testing (unless you have external firewall between your Oracle server and the internet)

Comment: I ended up using port 25 and localhost as host. I also used a third party tool called Stunnel for the SSL encapsulation.